# Problem of Unicode in Struts application

Tags: unicode, struts

I have some International character to be display in my struts project. I have stored the character in my DB. So when i retrive it from DB to JSP it display something like

`&#2344;&#2375;&#2346;&#2366;`I have spend  2 whole day solving it going throung different forums but i couldnt find proper solution. So this is my last hope. I hope someone will through light on me.

If i go the link http://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp and put the iso-8859-1 character `&#2344;&#2375;&#2346;&#2366;` to it and convert it, it display my International character.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have the html entities stored in the db?

Comment: No this is what is stored in DB '&#2344;&#2375;&#2346;&#2366;'

Answer (score 0):

> No this is what is stored in DB `'&#2344;&#2375;&#2346;&#2366;'`

That is what I meant by html entities. When you output this string using jstl `c:out` it will escape the `&` signs again to avoid html injection and cross site scripting attacks. The html source code of the rendered page would then look like:

```
&amp;#2344;&amp;#2375;&amp;#2346;&amp;#2366;
```

This means that the browser will render the `&` sign literally.

The web page you linked seems to offer the *unconverted* string as a txt download, since contains only characters in the ascii range. If you open this file with a browser it will probably try to interpret it as html and show the corresponding international characters.

You should investigate why there are already encoded characters in your db, it would be better to store the actual bytes in a defined encoding like utf-8 instead.

Comment: Horstmann, Thank you so much. Now i understand whats going on. But instead of storing it as a byte, will it be possible to decode the character and then pass to JSP. WIll that be possible?

Comment: @JavaGuy: It is possible by setting the `escapeXml` of `c:out` to false, but I would not recommend it. Doing so would allow an user to display arbitrary html and javascript in your pages, which could be used for some malicious effects.

Comment: @JavaGuy: I you need assistance in figuring out why these encoded characters get saved in the db in the first place, please ask a new question and include the relevant parts of your jsp and action class.

Answer (score 0):

When You are inserting data into MySql database, do you use `NVARCHAR` type for the field, and if so, did you put a `N` before the table.FieldName?

You have to put it in database in Unicode way which is available with putting  **`N`** befor the field name